# HTML grid/table options (virtual rendering/scrolling)

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm looking for a solid, high-performance HTML grid/table with *virtual rendering/scrolling*. So far I've compiled the following possible options:

- dhtmlxGrid
- datatables
- tablesorter
- www.jtable
- SlickGrid
- trirand.com
- flexigrid

First, I would appreciate if anyone can add more options to this list for consideration.

Second, can anyone offer any "real world" experience using a HTML grid/table for a high-performance web site ... 10-100k concurrent users, and issues such as with browser compatibility, etc.

Comment: Datatables is far from perfect from performance stand point. I'm using it actively in a high data project myself and facing rendering problems constantly. If you are serious about the speed, you probably best to end up building your specific system, maybe you can try using react.js (or similar) for best performance rendering.

Answer (score 5):

My site is a high-traffic, high data (1 million+ records) SAAS marketing automation system that uses [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net) exclusively.

Chances are, if it's a reputable alternative to Datatables I've tried it over the last year, and site traffic isn't a problem with any solution I've found....all seem to do really well that way and are (relatively) low overhead.

The trick is dealing with a lot of data. Many options want you to send an HTML table to the javascript and it will build your grid by crawling the dom.  It sounds great until you start dealing with more than a couple of thousand records, then it starts grinding.  Datatables overcomes this by allowing you to build your data server-side, either X records at a time or X+a defined overage (called pipelining) that allows you to buffer more results than the user needs on each query to allow faster paging.  It's what makes it appear to work so quickly, almost unnoticeable to the user if you have your queries optimized well.  There's a full API to allow you to modify data on the fly (such as with an editable table).

Datatables is also the only one (at least at the time of my search) that fully integrates with jQuery ThemeRoller.  In my app, that means that with a simple switch of a CSS file (autogenerated at jqueryui.com) I can completely retheme my entire app, including datatables.  It's allowed me to sell co-branding as an upcharge and it literally takes me 5 minutes to do.

Finally, Datatables has a thriving community, plugins such as download and export to CSV or PDF, and an author that will answer questions seemingly 24/7.  I suspect many of his concepts will be incorporated into the future jQuery UI Grid, which is due out in the not-so-distant future....since he is contributing on the project.